# How to censor the MAC from a dmesg output?

Tags: privacy, mac-address

INPUT:

```
dmesg | grep [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
f0:de:f1:11:22:33
...
```

OUTPUT:

```
dmesg | SOMEMAGIC | grep [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
f0:de:f1:52:22:17
...
```

How did I get the "52:22:17"?

```
echo 11:22:33 | cksum | sed "s/.\{2\}/&:/g" | cut -d: -f-3
52:22:17
```

In this way, I can "censor" my MAC addresses NIC specific string when I have to give a `dmesg` output. (the "SOMEMAGIC" is a magical thing that can do this automatically for all the MAC that could be found in a `dmesg` AND preserve (the NIC specific string, just replacing it with another string) that ex.: wlan0 MAC is X, wlan1 MAC is Y)

**Question:** How do I censor the NIC specific string of a MAC address from a `dmesg` output, but preserve that there could be several different MAC addresses?

UPDATE#1: in "my" way, as in the example we could generate a table that consist about ~16 million lines (16*16 * 16*16 * 16*16 = 16^2 = 16 777 216) - so it's not good, since it could be found out what was the original MAC!

UPDATE#2: the solution must be case insensitive, so it shouldn't matter if the MAC is in upper or lowercase

Comment: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3071/33055

Answer (score 0):

To `grep` the mac addresses case insensitive, to get a better match you should extend the pattern to match hexadecimal values, and to have less positives match all the 6 pairs of hexadecimal characters:

```
dmesg | grep -i [0-9a-f][0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]
```

To replace **any** number of MACs that can appear multiple times, with a random one, and where the random ones **never** match one of (other) MACs, you have to first know all different MACs that occur in the dmesg output text, say this is a list L. Then map each of the elements in L to a random MAC that does not occur in L, and replace each MAC address according to the map.

I am not an even a beginner in `awk`, but I think the above, with these requirements is beyond its capabilities. I would seriously consider doing such a thing in python/ruby/perl.

However there might be a shortcut if you only have MAC addresses in your `dmesg` output that have the bit for globally unique OUI (Organizationally Unique Identifier) set. These are the ones with bit one (1) set in the first hex character (i.e. with a value `2`, `3`, `6`, `7`, `a`, `b`, `e`, `f`). This is normal for officially released hardware. If that is the case you can map each of the MAC addresses to a "locally administered" MAC address (bit 1 cleared), without having to be afraid that your random MAC address (with bit 1 cleared) just happens to match an existing one. In that case you just have to keep the mapping (for occurrences in a later stage of the file), not buffer against possible clashes of random with real MACs.
This restriction might simplify things enough for programs like `awk` to be able to implement your requirements (assuming they are not able to in the more restrictive case).

Please be aware that the use of six byte MAC-48 already has been "extended" by eight byte EUI-64 identifiers. I haven't seen those yet myself, but they might show up in your `dmesg` output.

A python program that does the difficult case:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import sys
import re
import io
from random import randint

MAC48_REGEX = re.compile(r"""
   (?x)(?i)               # free spacing mode, ignore case
   ([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}   # five times two hex-characters, followed by : or -
   ([0-9A-F]{2})          # final two hex-characters
""")


class MatchMAC48(object):
    MAX_MAC = 256 ** 6 - 1
    def __init__(self):
        self._mac_map = {}
        self._buffer = io.StringIO()

    def __call__(self, line):
        """analyse the input for input MAC addresses and store them"""
        self._buffer.write(line)
        res = MAC48_REGEX.search(line)
        if not res:
            return line  # no MACs
        index = 0
        while res:
            self._mac_map[res.group()] = None
            index += res.span()[1]
            res = MAC48_REGEX.search(line[index:])

    def generate_map(self):
        """generate a unique mapping MAC for each of the MAC address keys"""
        for k in self._mac_map:
            if self._mac_map[k] is not None:
                continue
            r = None
            while (r is None or 
                  r in self._mac_map or         # not an original MAC 
                  r in self._mac_map.values()): # twice the same random MAC
                  r = randint(0, self.MAX_MAC)
            ml = []
            for i in range(6):
                ml.insert(0, u'{:02x}'.format(r & 255))
                r >>= 8
            self._mac_map[k] = u':'.join(ml)

    def dump(self, fp=sys.stdout):
        """dump the cached StringIO buffer"""
        mm48.generate_map()  # in case not yet generated
        x = self._buffer.getvalue()
        for k in self._mac_map:
            x = x.replace(k, self._mac_map[k])
        fp.write(x)


mm48 = MatchMAC48()

for line in sys.stdin:
    mm48(line.decode('utf-8'))

mm48.dump()
```